# Data not saved on application Close

Tags: c#, database

```
public static string cs = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename="+Application.StartupPath+"\\TestDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
```

I have tried the above code for making the string global. The problem is that the data is saved until the application is open. As soon as I restart the application, the changes are not reflected in the database file. Also help me where to keep the database during deployment. I am using SqlServer 2008 and the database location is the Application folder

I have this code:

```
 SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\TestDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"); 
 cn.Open (); 
 string ins = "insert into table1 values ('"+textBox1.Text+"')"; 
 SqlCommand c = new SqlCommand(ins, cn ); 
 c.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
 string exts = "select * from table1 where kri='"+textBox1.Text+"'"; 
 SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(exts,cnn); 
 DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 
 adp.Fill(dt); 
 MessageBox.Show(dt.Rows[0][0].ToString()); 
 cn.Close ();
```

Comment: That string would have nothing to do with actually *committing* the changes to the database. That's just the connection string. Where's the code you're using the make the changes to the database?

Comment: `SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\TestDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
            cn.Open ();
            string ins = "insert into table1 values ('"+textBox1.Text+"')";
            SqlCommand c = new SqlCommand(ins, cn );
            c.ExecuteNonQuery();


            string exts = "select * from table1 where kri='"+textBox1.Text+"'";
            SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(exts,cnn);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
adp.Fill(dt);
MessageBox.Show(dt.Rows[0][0].ToString());
cn.Close ();
`

Comment: Edit your question with that code instead of putting it in the comments please.

Comment: Please *put the code in the post*. Moreover, perhaps you should start with a tutorial on ADO.NET. You can't expect a full tutorial from a Q&A site.

Answer (score 1):

The first issue here is that you kind of misunderstand a connection string. Think of a connection string like your address. It's not you, but it's where you reside. That connection string is just stating where the data you want to manipulate *resides.*

With that understanding we can answer the question about what to do in deployment pretty easily. During deployment you will load the database on to a real SQL Server. That SQL Server will *reside* somewhere, and thus be the address to that database. Therefore, when deployed, you'll change that connection string because the data you want to manipulate will *reside* somewhere else.

As far as persisting changes to the database. I guess that really depends on what framework you're using to *make* changes to the database. But let's just work out an example with the plain old ADO classes. Let's assume we have a table named `tbl`. And in that table there is an `ID` and a `Name`, and we want to `UPDATE` that name. So, we might do it like this:

```
using (SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(connString))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE tbl SET Name = @Name WHERE ID = @ID"))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", someName);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", someId);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

In this example, `someName` and `someId` may come from text boxes. They may be stored somewhere else. That's up to you on where to get those from. But that would persist the changes to the database.

Now let's work on housing that connection string. We definitely don't want that hard coded like that. The most common approach is to put it into the `app.config/web.config` file. So, let's do that. In the `app.config/web.config` file add a key to the `<connectionStrings>` section:

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Default"
      connectionString="{Enter Connection String Here}"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Alright, now that we've done that, let's get that connection string from there instead. First add a reference to `System.Configuration`. Next, modify that line of code to be this:

```
public static string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Default"]
```

And so now, when you deploy this application, you just fix up the connection string during deployment.

Comment: I get what you are trying to say but see i am facing following problems while i am performing insert operation

Comment: @Seeya, I've asked you already to please put that code in your question so I can actually read it. Once you do that, I can do something with it. Help me, help you, please.

Comment: I get what you are trying to say but see i am facing following problems while i am performing insert operation

I have a database named TestDb.mdf in my Application's Folder. now i want to insert some values in that database. The values must be stored there permanently. But the thing is when i am Debugging my application the database file is automatically copied to the Debug folder and changes are made in that file , which are not reflected in the database that is in the application folder. When i stop debugging the database file in debug folder is missing and when i again try to ..continue...

Comment: @Seeya, it appears to me that you have some kind of post-build script that's destroying that database. At this point you need to get those details together and ask a much different question. Now, the next time you ask a question, spend a lot more time on it. Remember that we have **no context** and *no idea* what you've done or what you're trying to do. You have to help us ... help you.

Comment: fetch the data inserted, it is missing. So i think the database changes are made in Debug folder and not in Application Folder. How to make string global for such problems because the `|DataDirectory|` and the `Application.Startuppath` points to the `bin\debug\TestDb.mdf`

Comment: @Seeya, and now you're yet going down another road. Get all these details together and ask a different question because this one I can tell is going to get closed.